# cannot write form values to spreadsheet

Tags: jquery, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I create a leave request form - code attached and pass the values as JSON object to the server side script but then the form freezes. It does not return any values. there are two problems

1. How to make the server script write values to the spreadsheet
2. How to get the current Date-time stamp for the record.

   ```
   <head>

   <style>

   body
   {
       width:80%;
       margin-left:auto;
       margin-right:auto;
       font-size:16pt;
       font-family:Verdana;
       padding: 5px;
   }
   </style>

   </head>

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css">

   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

   <script>

   function sendval(){
   var leaverec = new Object();

   leaverec.startdate = $("#txtFromDate").datepicker("getDate");
   leaverec.enddate = $("#txtToDate").datepicker("getDate");
   leaverec.contactnum = $("#contactnum").val();

   jsonleaverec = JSON.stringify(leaverec);

   google.script.run
             .withSuccessHandler(onsuccess)
             .processLeaveForm(jsonleaverec))
   }

   function onsuccess(retval){
      alert("Leave Form Submitted Successfully");
   }

   </script>

   <div>

   <form id="leaveapp">

   <?var logged_user = getcurruser(); ?>
   <label><?=logged_user?></label>

   <p> Start Date : <input type="text" name="StartDate" id="txtFromDate" /> </p>
   <p> End Date :   <input type="text" name="EndDate" id="txtToDate" /> </p>
   <p> Contact Number : <input type="text" name="Contactnum" id="contactnum" /> </p>

   <script>
   $("#txtFromDate").datepicker({
           minDate: 0,
           maxDate: "+60D",
           numberOfMonths: 2,
           onSelect: function(selected) {
               $("#txtToDate").datepicker("option","minDate", selected)
           }
       });

   </script>

   <script>

   $("#txtToDate").datepicker({ 
           minDate: 0,
           maxDate:"+60D",
           numberOfMonths: 2,
           onSelect: function(selected) {
               $("#txtFromDate").datepicker("option","maxDate", selected)
           }
       });

   </script>

    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick=senddata() />

   </form>

   </div>

   </html>
   ```

the google script is as follows

```
function getcurruser(){
 var current_user = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('curruser');
 return current_user;
}

function processLeaveForm(jsonleaverec){
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById("12345678901234567890");
  var sheet = doc.getSheetByName("LeaveRequests")
  var d = new Date();
  var currentTime = d.toLocaleTimeString();
  var curruser = getcurruser();

  var leaveform = eval("(" + jsonleaverec + ")");

  var leavestart = leaveform.StartDate;
  var leaveend = leaveform.EndDate;
  var contactnum = leaveform.contactnum; 

  var leaverange = sheet.getrange((sheet.getLastRow()+1),1);

  leaverange.setValue(curruser);


  return "success";

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easier way would be to send in a form, you don't have to construct a JSON. Send it's HTML with document.getElementById("leaveapp");.

In HTML you would refactor:

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onsuccess).processLeaveForm(document.getElementById("leaveapp"));
```

And in code.gs

```
function processLeaveForm(jsonleaverec){
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById("12345678901234567890");
  var sheet = doc.getSheetByName("LeaveRequests")
  var d = new Date();
  var currentTime = d.toLocaleTimeString();
  var curruser = getcurruser();

  var leavestart = leaveform.StartDate;
  var leaveend = leaveform.EndDate;
  var contactnum = leaveform.contactnum;
```

You also have to remove form submit on enter/button so you don't end up with a blank page:

```
$('#leaveapp').on("keyup keypress", function(e) {
  var code = e.keyCode || e.which; 
  if (code  == 13) {               
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried your instructions, but when I press the submit button nothing happens. I continue to be on the same page. I am a newbie, any help would be great.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long. Refactor your button to `<input type="button" id="sendButton" />`, and add to Jquery you button click. `$("#sendButton").click(function(event)
  {
    event.preventDefault(); // cancel default behavior
//   processLeaveForm(jsonleaverec) logic here
  });`